# Keras Autoencoder: Target data is missing. Model expects target data to be provided in fit()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am encountering an error when fitting an autoencoder model. I'm trying to translate text between 2 languages.

Here is my code:

```
xLines = np.genfromtxt('data-1.ar',dtype='str',delimiter=',' )
yLines = np.genfromtxt('data-1.en',dtype='str',delimiter=',' )
    
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=maxTokens,
    split="whitespace",
    ngrams=None,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=outputLength
)
vectorize_layer.adapt(vocab_data)

def vectorize_text(text):
    text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)

    return vectorize_layer(text)


arDataset = vectorize_text(xLines)
enDataset = vectorize_text(yLines)

print(arDataset.shape)
print(enDataset.shape)

x = keras_nlp.layers.TokenAndPositionEmbedding(
    vocabulary_size=maxTokens,
    sequence_length=outputLength,
    embedding_dim=EMBED_DIM,
    mask_zero=True,
)(encoder_inputs)

encoder_outputs = keras_nlp.layers.TransformerEncoder(
    intermediate_dim=INTERMEDIATE_DIM, num_heads=NUM_HEADS
)(inputs=x)
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_outputs)


# Decoder
decoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="decoder_inputs")
encoded_seq_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, EMBED_DIM), name="decoder_state_inputs")

x = keras_nlp.layers.TokenAndPositionEmbedding(
    vocabulary_size=maxTokens,
    sequence_length=outputLength,
    embedding_dim=EMBED_DIM,
    mask_zero=True,
)(decoder_inputs)

x = keras_nlp.layers.TransformerDecoder(
    intermediate_dim=INTERMEDIATE_DIM, num_heads=NUM_HEADS
)(decoder_sequence=x, encoder_sequence=encoded_seq_inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
decoder_outputs = keras.layers.Dense(enChars, activation="softmax")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(
    [
        decoder_inputs,
        encoded_seq_inputs,
    ],
    decoder_outputs,
)
decoder_outputs = decoder([decoder_inputs, encoder_outputs])

transformer = keras.Model(
    [encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs],
    decoder_outputs,
    name="transformer",
)

transformer.summary()
transformer.compile(
    "rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
transformer.fit([arDataset,enDataset], epochs=100)
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with
> loss=categorical_crossentropy, and therefore expects target data to be
> provided in `fit()`.

The shape of both my datasets is (99, 22)

**Update 1**

I've tried changing the fit arguments but still encountering a similar error.

```
transformer.fit(arDataset,enDataset, epochs=100)
transformer.fit(x=arDataset,y=enDataset, epochs=100)
```

> ValueError: Layer "transformer" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1
> input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0'
> shape=(None, 22) dtype=int64>]

I'm not sure what the error means and how to resolve it.

Comment: What is your question? The error is pretty clear, you did not provide targets (the y values).

Comment: Sorry i did try to change the arguments but I'm still encountering a similar error. I'm not sure whats the right way of calling the fit. I've updated the posted with my latest attempt

Comment: Since this is an autoencoder, you need to pass the input as labels too, like: transformer.fit([arDataset,enDataset], [arDataset,enDataset], epochs=100)

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy. I'm getting a different error now: "ValueError: Shapes (None, 22) and (None, 22, 74) are incompatible". I'm guessing thats because the inout isnt oneHotEncoded. If so, is there an easy way to transform the indices from vectorize_layer?